# iPad mini 4 restarts itself when shaken

Tags: ios, ipad

Today I just noticed that my iPad mini 4 restarts itself when shaken. I started to notice it first today when I took off its clear case to clean the back. I also noticed that when I hard reset it sometimes a gold (sometimes white and gray) colored screen flashes before restarting itself. What could be the cause of this problem?

BTW/ the iPad mini 4 is a 16gb wifi model and running on the latest version of iOS (10.2.1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem (battery connector loose, probably). If you need it fixed, bring it to an Apple Store or talk to Apple at https://getsupport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an hardware issue. The first thing I would suggest is to stop shaking it! :)
What ever loose connector you have there might stay loose which will force you to take it to apple \ local repair store.

I think it's better to take it for a repair now. I will be a lot easier for the repair guy to find the problem while it is still half working.